# How to set focus() on dropdown list, using javascript in php script

Tags: php, javascript, html, focus

I am unable to set focus to my php page dc-test.php (this is a frames page: topFrame and botFrame) dropdown list, which has 2 dropdown lists and are dependent. These dropdown lists values are populated from a table. Unable to set focus for the first dropdown and later after the reload for the second dependent dropdown list. Pl see my code below, need your help ! Sorry if i am repeating this question on this forum, because I was unable to find the right answer.

Pl look at function firstfield(), it does't set the focus to dropdown list in the below code.

```
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
function reload(form)
{
var val=form.cat.options[form.cat.options.selectedIndex].value;
self.location='dc-test.php?cat=' + val ;
}

function firstfield()
{
document.topFrame.cat.focus();
}
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="firstfield();">

<?php
$dbservertype='mysql';
$servername='localhost';
$dbusername='aaa';
$dbpassword='234!@';
$dbname='test';

connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
function connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbuser,$dbpassword)
{
global $link;
$link=mysql_connect ("$servername","$dbuser","$dbpassword");
if(!$link){die("Could not connect to MySQL");}
mysql_select_db("$dbname",$link) or die ("could not open db".mysql_error());
}
// End of DB connection

@$cat=$_GET['cat'];
if(strlen($cat) > 0 and !is_numeric($cat)){ 
echo "Data Error";
exit;
}


$quer2=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT Ac_desc, Ac_code FROM ACMAST order by Ac_desc");


/////// Second drop down list we will check if category is selected else we will display all the subcategory/////
if(isset($cat) and strlen($cat) > 0){
$quer=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT Add1 FROM ACMAST where Ac_code=$cat order by   Add1");
}

echo "<form name='f1'>";
echo "<table width='100%' height='39'  border='0' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0'>";
echo "  <tr>";
echo "    <td width='12%'>.</td>";
echo "    <td width='7%'><span class='sty1'> Customer</span></td>";
echo "    <td width='27%'><select name='cat' onchange=\"reload(this.form);        showUser(this.value);\">
<option value=''>Select Name</option>";
while($noticia2 = mysql_fetch_array($quer2)) {
if($noticia2['Ac_code']==@$cat){echo "<option selected value='$noticia2[Ac_code]'>$noticia2[Ac_desc]</option>"."<BR>";}
else{echo  "<option value='$noticia2[Ac_code]'>$noticia2[Ac_desc]</option>";}
}
echo "</select>";

echo "</td>";
echo "    <td width='6%'><span class='sty1'>Address</span></td>";
echo "    <td width='48%'> </span><select name='subcat'>";
while($noticia = mysql_fetch_array($quer)) {
echo  "<option value='$noticia[Add1]'>$noticia[Add1]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo "</td>";
echo "  </tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
</body>        
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you assign an id to your select box and then use

```
document.getElementById("cat").focus();
```

to access an element inside a frame use

```
window.frames[0].getElementById("cat").focus();
```

`frames[0]` just change the number 0 to the index of your frame. e.g. if you have 2 frames and you want to access the second one it would be `frames[1]`

Comment: have you tried debugging your function? use firebug and console.log() to see if it gets the correct element

Comment: Stratton, this worked for me, but the problem is not resolved completely, because when we are using single file this works:        <body onLoad="document.f1.cat.focus();">   If we have this in frames, it does't, kindy check how to set focus for first frame.

Comment: Straton, it is not working ! focus is not getting set to any frame now, pl check

Comment: Straton, I have tried with even this it is not working: window.frames[0].f1.cat.focus();